# log multiple assemblies using log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, .net-assembly, log4net-configuration

After lots of issues, finally I managed to configure log4net for my window service.

I am pretty new to it and today I started configuring it. I have these below doubts.

1) **I need to use that into multiple assemblies. Say I have an assembly 'A' which is added as reference in assembly 'B' which is mine main assembly where I have reference of log4net.I need to log both assembly 'A' and 'B'.**

2) My application is multi-threaded and use lots of thread. So is log4net is thread safe?

3) I am using this below config in my app.config. I am not much aware what’s the use of it. But I don’t want to use unnecessary parameters.

```xml
<log4net>
     <root>
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
     </root>
     <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="C:\logs\log.txt"/>
       <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
       <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
       <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
       <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
       <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n"/>
       </layout>
     </appender>   
</log4net>
```

Comment: What is your question excactly?

Comment: question exactly specified in point 1 and 2

Comment: Please use question marks (?) next time, so it is clearer.

Comment: There is a good FAQ that I think answers all your questions... http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html the documentation is pretty good too, I work out how to use it within a day by just reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />` under appender section. I twill increase the logging performance.

log4net is threadsafe.

```
<maximumFileSize value="10MB" /> //For 100 Kb configuration there will be lot of files.
```

`<datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd" />` //It will hint the logger to create a new file per date.

Create a static class for Logger and call the static function from every assembly where you want to use.

**Sample Class for logging:**

```
public static class Logger
    {
        static Logger()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        public static void Log()
        {
            string methodName = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().Name;
            string moduleName = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;

            var appLog = LogManager.GetLogger(loggername);
            appLog.Error(...);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was doing same only. Say I added log4net reference in assembly A which added as reference in assembly B. Now if I create a static class in assembly A which will used log4net and Assembly B can utilize it then in that case log4net dll reference got to be added in assembly B also. What you say.

Comment: You have no need to add log4net dll in dll B because tou will log using dll A.

Comment: Thanks Romil, I have resolved issue. The log4net methods reference exits only in current assembly where it is added say A here. So i created a class suggested in below link as a help for someone who will read this post later.

http://actcode.com/2009/11/net-application-logging-with-log4net-in-console-file-database/

Comment: Romil your MinmalLock suggestion is wrong. It is slower than not using minimal locking because the logfile will be opened/closed once for each log output. See: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock.html

Answer (score 0):

1. that's not a problem; just use `ILog` as usual in assembly B.
   just make sure you call `Configure()` once in your application's lifetime.
2. Yes.
3. I recommend familiarizing yourself with log4net. a simple [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=log4net%20tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) or a look at the [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) should do the trick.

Comment: That i am doing now. I created added reference in assembly B and used that object ILog for logging. In assembly A I did not added log4net reference and now is there a way that without adding log4net reference in both assemblies i can log.

Assembly A is added as reference in assembly B

Comment: so, you're asking whether you can use `ILog` without referencing the assembly in which it's defined? the answer is obviously 'no'...

Comment: In assembly B i have referenced log4net dll. In order to log assembly A do i need to add log4net reference again in it.

Comment: see my previous comment... in any assembly where you wish to use the `ILog` interface, you have to reference the assembly which defines it (i.e log4net).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <root>
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
     </root>
```

It will log only in debug mode, so make following entry in config:

```
 <root>
       <level value="ALL"/>
       <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
     </root>
```